# get a massive error when trying to use wp_rss

Tags: php, wordpress, rss

I am trying to add an rss feed to my site and when I use the wp_rss method like this:

```
  <?php
require ABSPATH . WPINC . '/rss.php';
wp_rss ( 'http://miletich2.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default?alt=rss', 5 )
?>
```

I get a massive error shown below:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function split() in /home/vagrant/Code/creativeforces/wp-includes/rss.php:117 Stack trace: #0 [internal function]: MagpieRSS->feed_start_element(Resource id #6, 'gd:image', Array) #1 /home/vagrant/Code/creativeforces/wp-includes/rss.php(84): xml_parse(Resource id #6, '<?xml version='...') #2 /home/vagrant/Code/creativeforces/wp-includes/rss.php(596): MagpieRSS->__construct('<?xml version='...') #3 /home/vagrant/Code/creativeforces/wp-includes/rss.php(495): _response_to_rss(Object(stdClass)) #4 /home/vagrant/Code/creativeforces/wp-includes/rss.php(901): fetch_rss('http://miletich...') #5 /home/vagrant/Code/creativeforces/wp-content/themes/creativeforces/page-media.php(30): wp_rss('http://miletich...', 5) #6 /home/vagrant/Code/creativeforces/wp-includes/template-loader.php(75): include('/home/vagrant/C...') #7 /home/vagrant/Code/creativeforces/wp-blog-header.php(19): require_once('/home/vagrant/C...') #8 /home/vagrant/Code/creativeforces/index.php(17): require('/home/vagrant/C. in /home/vagrant/Code/creativeforces/wp-includes/rss.php on line 117
```

I have no idea what to do from here. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: do you use php 7? `split` was removed in php 7.

Comment: Oh, I am using php 5.6. and I am using the most recent version of wordpress.

Comment: Would wordpress be using php 7

Comment: I tried your exact code on php 5.6 and I don't get any error. (I confirm that in line 117 there is a call to `split()`)

Answer (score 0):

`split()` is not available in your PHP installation. It was removed in PHP 7.

You can verify this using the code below:

```
<?php
echo 'PHP version is '.phpversion().'<br><br>';

$funcs = get_defined_functions();

if(in_array('split', $funcs['internal']))
{
    echo 'split() exists<br><br>';
}
else
{
    echo 'split() does not exist<br><br>';
}

sort($funcs['internal']);
echo '<pre>'.print_r($funcs['internal'], true).'</pre>';
```